# Heroku | How to retrieve the staging database?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, heroku

My app is deployed on heroku.

In order to prepare and test everything before the app is launched I create most of my products on my staging environnement. Then I will copy it to the production env.
Sorry for this silly question, I've no idea how to this with heroku...

```
$  heroku run bash
$ env | grep -i database
DATABASE_URL=postgres://prmzmsxxxxgc:fd2f444cefedfEEEcd0982e363826c4032ecbfaa391526c3422222227e6bb145@ec2-176-34-184-174.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:5432/xxxxxxxxxxxk
```

How do I connect to my db ? 
How can I send it on my computer and use it in another Env?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

1. you can connect your local project to the heroku database by adding `DATABASE_URL` to your environment variables:

```
DATABASE_URL=postgres://prmzmsxxxxgc:fd2f444cefedfEEEcd0982e363826c4032ecbfaa391526c3422222227e6bb145@ec2-176-34-184-174.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:5432/xxxxxxxxxxxk
```

2. You can generate a dump of the heroku database and then mount it locally, you can see the instructions [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export).